# How to prove that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - 2n + 3}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - 2n + 3}$ is convergent. I was trying to find a series that is larger than $1/(n^2-2n+3)$ that converges, but am having a hard time. I have gotten to the point that $1/(n^2 -2n) > 1/(n^2-2n+3)$, but am unsure how to find a series larger than $1/(n^2-2n)$ that doesn't make the series negative.

Thanks,,

Comment: Try to write using Mathjax

Comment: your denominator is a little bigger than $(n-1)^2$   so the reciprocal is a little smaller. Next point:  the first few terms don't matter, ignore $n=1$

Answer (score 3):

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $n^2-2n+3>\frac{n^2}2$, since
\begin{align}
n^2-2n+3>\frac{n^2}2&\iff n^2-4n+6>0\\
&\iff(n-2)^2+2>0,
\end{align}
which is true. So,
$$
(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\frac1{n^2-2n+3}<\frac2{n^2},
$$
and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{n^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle{a_n=\frac{1}{n^2-2n+3}}$ and $\displaystyle{b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}}$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2-2n+3}=1$$
Now as $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}}$ is a convergent series, your series also converges by the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n^2-2n+3}{n^2}=1$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2-2n+3}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=1\implies$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ s.t. "$n\ge N\implies \frac{1}{n^2-2n+3}<\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}$". Hence $\forall n>N$,
$$\sum_{i=N}^n \frac{1}{i^2-2i+3}<\sum_{i=N}^n\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{i^2}<\sum_{i=N}^{+\infty}\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=N}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}$$

(where the last term is finite).

$\implies \{\sum_{i=N}^n \frac{1}{i^2-2i+3}|\ n>N \}$ is upper bounded $\implies\{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2-2i+3}|\ n>N \}$ is upper bounded $\implies \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{i^2-2i+3}$ converges since all terms are positive.

Answer (score 1):

*For your curiosity since you have the answer for the convergence*

Let us see what is the value considering the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2-2n+3}$$ Rewrite
$$ \frac 1{n^2-2n+3}=\frac 1{a-b}\left( \frac 1{n-a}-\frac 1{n-b}\right)$$ where
$$a=1-i\sqrt 2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=1+i\sqrt 2 $$ are the roots of the quadratic.

Using generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\frac 1{a-b}\Big(\left(H_{p-a}-H_{-a} \right)-\left(H_{p-b}-H_{-b} \right) \Big)$$ Use the asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{H_{-b}-H_{-a}}{a-b}-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1-a-b}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ Replace $(a,b)$ by their definition and simplify the complex numbers
$$S_p=\frac{1+\sqrt{2} \pi  \coth \left(\sqrt{2} \pi
   \right)}{4} -\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ this gives an approximation in relative error of $1$% if $p=4$,  of $0.1$% if $p=8$,   of $0.01$% if $p=16$ and so on.